# Access submitted form data in custom callback before hook_mail_alter()

Tags: hooks, 8, forms, emails

I wan't to alter contact form recipient according to what user chose in one of the dropdown fields of my Contact form.

I implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` in order to add custom submit callback like this

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_callback';
```

to get submitted data.

I thought I could use `State API` in `my_custom_callback()` to store received data temporally and use it's value in `hook_mail_alter()` but it looks like `hook_mail_alter()` is called before my custom callback.

This is what the order of callbacks looks like:

1. Default Submit callback of Contact form;
2. `hook_mail_alter()`;
3. `my_custom_callback`.

I wander if there is any way to change this order to this:

1. `my_custom_callback`;
2. Default Submit callback of Contact form;
3. `hook_mail_alter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a submit callback at all? The built contact message is available in hook_mail_alter(), you can just access the submitted data there?

This is from a custom project where we did something similar:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {
    /** @var \Drupal\contact\Entity\Message $contact_message */
    $contact_message = $message['params']['contact_message'];

    if ($contact_message->bundle() != 'feedback') {
      return;
    }

    $recipient_address = $contact_message->get('yourfield')->value;
    if (\Drupal::service('email.validator')->isValid($recipient_address)) {
      $message['to'] = $recipient_address;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the relevant values for sending the mail in a [temporary table](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) when my_custom_callback is executed, and then process the data in this table using a [cron job](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) or [batch job](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example!batch_example.module/7).  Batch would probably be better - gives you the tools to lock records, etc.  You could run the batch using a cron job :)